# How to change colour of cells in Excel using programming languages

Tags: excel

I have googled a while for the methods to create excel files (*.xlsx, not the csv files) using programming languages, such as C++ or PHP. here is an example, http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/

But Ideally, I want to be able to specify the colours for each cell. For example, in VBScript using COM object Excel.Application, the code looks like:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
With objWorksheet
.Cells(1,1).Interior.Color=RGB(245,245,245)
...
...
...
End With
objWorkbook.SaveAs("sample.xlsx")
objExcel.Quit
```

How can I do this without the use of COM object? I need the program to work platform-independent so COM object is not a good choice.

Update: [here](https://helloacm.com/how-to-create-a-picture-by-changing-cell-colors-in-excel-using-php-and-vbscript/) is an interesting post, that generates the VBS file and double click the VBS file will give you a nice picture in Excel by drawing cells with different colors.

Comment: yes,  VBA is not good. I want to write a C++ or PHP program that runs under Linux

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that if you can't open Excel on the Linux box. the only other option I can think of is to generate the necessary XML details with color and everything, then convert that to an .xlsx. But I have no idea how to do that, or even if it's a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify cell backgrounds using python and the [XLSX Writer module](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/). While it is not the C++ or PHP language you mentioned, Python is cross platform and the code below works on the Fedora box I tested with.

First, you need python and the module mentioned above. You can install the module by doing this:

```python
pip install xlsxwriter
```

Next, we are going to modify the first [tutorial](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/tutorial01.html) to provide a little color to the "Total" value.

```python
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

green_format = workbook.add_format()
green_format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
green_format.set_bg_color('#008000')

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col, item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)', green_format)

workbook.close()
```

The things that were added are these lines. This utilizes the [`set_bg_color`](http://bbs.konotes.org/workdoc/python/xlsxwriter/format.html#set_bg_color) function.

```python
green_format = workbook.add_format()
green_format.set_pattern(1)  # This is optional when using a solid fill.
green_format.set_bg_color('green')
```

And the `=SUM` row was modified to use this green format:

```python
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)', green_format)
```

This code creates a green cell at `B5`.

[image: Excel Green Cell]

A note about the color: I provided the color `'green'`, because that is one of the few [colors](http://bbs.konotes.org/workdoc/python/xlsxwriter/working_with_colors.html#colors) that are mapped to an RGB value. If you need to use something other than these colors, you can provide an RGB value. `#008000` maps to `green`

```python
green_format.set_bg_color('#008000')
```

This line is functionally identical to the one provided above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP, there are at least two different toolkits, which will generate Excel files without the use of COM Object :
[PhpExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and [ExcelWriterXML](http://excelwriterxml.sourceforge.net/).

For ExcelWriterXML for instance, changing the background color is `$format->bgColor('Black');` , see complete example on the site.

Another way is to produce xlsx files (which are XML inside) through a template engine like TinyButStrong.